# Accessing portions of a dynamic array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, sdl-2

I know, another dynamic array question, this one is a bit different though so maybe it'll be worth answering. I am making a terrain generator in C with SDL, I am drawing 9 chunks surrounding the screen, proportional to the screen size, that way terrains can be generated easier in the future.

This means that I have to be able to resize the array at any given point, so I made a dynamic array (at least according to an answer I found on stack it is) and everything SEEMS to work fine, nothing is crashing, it even draws a single tile....but just one. I am looking at it and yeah, sure enough it's iterating through the array but only writing to one portion of memory. I am using a struct called Tile that just holds the x, y, w, and h of a rectangle.

This is the code I am using to allocate the array

```
Tile* TileMap = (Tile*)malloc(0 * sizeof(Tile*));
int arrayLen = sizeof(TileMap);
TileMap = (Tile*)realloc(TileMap, (totalTiles) * sizeof(Tile));
arrayLen = sizeof(totalTiles * sizeof(Tile));
```

The totalTiles are just the number of tiles that I have calculated previously are on the screen, I've checked the math and it's correct, and it even allocates the proper amount of memory. Here is the code I use to initialize the array:

```
    //Clear all elements to zero.
for (int i = 0; i < arrayLen; i++)
{
    Tile tile = {};
    TileMap[i] = tile;
}
```

So what's weird to me is it is considering the size of a tile (16 bytes) * the totalTiles (78,000) is equaling 4....When I drill down into the array, it only has one single rect in it that gets cleared as well, so then when I go calculate the sizes of each tile:

```
//Figure out Y and heights
for (int i = startY; i <= (startY*(-1)) * 2; i += TILE_HEIGHT)
{
    TileMap[i].y = i * TILE_HEIGHT;
    TileMap[i].h = TILE_HEIGHT;
    //Figure out X and widths
    for (int j = startX; j <= (startX*(-1)) * 2; j += TILE_WIDTH)
    {
        TileMap[i].x = i * TILE_WIDTH;
        TileMap[i].w = TILE_WIDTH;
    }
}
```

*Side note, the startX is the negative offset I am using to draw chunks behind the camera, so I times it by -1 to make it positive and then time it by two to get one chunk in front of the camera

Alright, so obviously that only initializes one, and here is the render code

```
for (int i = 0; i < totalTiles; i++)
{
    SDL_Rect currentTile;
    currentTile.x = TileMap[i].x;
    currentTile.y = TileMap[i].y;
    currentTile.w = TileMap[i].w;
    currentTile.h = TileMap[i].h;

    SDL_RenderDrawRect(renderer, &currentTile);
}

free(TileMap);
```

So what am I doing wrong here? I mean I literally am just baffled right now...And before Vectors get recommended in place of dynamic arrays, I don't really like using them and I want to learn to deal with stuff like this, not just implement some simple fix.

Comment: `TileMap` is a pointer. `sizeof(TileMap)` is equivalent to `sizeof(Tile*)`. On a 32-bit platform, that is 4.  And `sizeof(totalTiles * sizeof(Tile))` is equivalent to `sizeof(size_t)`, which will also be 4.

Comment: Does it not? I'm not being snarky I'm asking legitimately. It takes the negative coordinate I need, says if i is less than or equal to the furthest screen coordinate, then increment i by the height of a tile, which gets you to the next tile on the next iteration right? I checked the math to make sure and it gives me the the correct coordinate on the screen...What is wrong about it?

Comment: your code is wrong, read carefully what @molbdnilo, has commented to you

Comment: `malloc(0 * sizeof(Tile*)` is equivalent to `malloc(0)` -- which is dodgy stuff. Checking the man page on my system for example, it says: "If size is 0, then malloc() returns either NULL, or a unique pointer value that can later be successfully passed to free()." If you get a NULL, you're in trouble.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Oh Shoot! You're right, I see what you're saying....I am a moron....hahahahaha

Comment: @gilez, you're right, except about the trouble.  *In this particular case*, receiving `NULL` as the result of `malloc(0)` is no problem at all, because that value -- whatever it is -- is used only as an argument to `realloc()`. `realloc()` has well-defined and appropriate behavior either way.  Not checking the return value of `realloc()`, on the other hand, will cause trouble if `realloc()` fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of confusion (which is commonplace with C pointers).

The following code doesn't provide expected answer :`arrayLen = sizeof(totalTiles * sizeof(Tile));`

`totalTiles * sizeof(Tile)` is not even a type, I'm surprised it compiles at all. *Edit : See molbnilo comment below.* so it provides the size of the return type.

Anyway, proper answer should be :
`arrayLen = totalTiles;`

Because that's what you need in your next loop  :

```
//Clear all elements to zero.
for (int i = 0; i < arrayLen; i++)
{
    Tile tile = {};
    TileMap[i] = tile;
}
```

You don't need the size of the table, you need its number of elements.

There are other confusions in your sample, they don't directly impact the rest of the code, but better correct them :

`Tile* TileMap = (Tile*)malloc(0 * sizeof(Tile*));` : avoid allocating a size of 0.

`int arrayLen = sizeof(TileMap);` : no, it's not the `arrayLen`, just the size of the pointer (hence 4 bytes on 32-bits binaries). Remember `TileMap` is not defined as a table, but as a pointer allocated with `malloc()` and then `realloc()`.

Comment: `sizeof` can take either an expression or a type. If you give it an expression, the result is the same as if you passed the expression's type (the expression is not evaluated).

Comment: So there was a lot of good stuff you pointed out, all of which has helped clean things up, but my core problem is still unsolved; how do I allocate many structs? I've looked at dozens of answers on here at this point but nothing has worked, it still will only allocate space for one single struct, even if I malloc a random number of bytes it still allocates 4 bytes, I assume that's because it's truncating it to be the size of one tile because of the cast but I can't find a work around for that....Any advice?

Comment: Excuse me, I meant for realloc, not malloc

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your line :
`TileMap = (Tile*)realloc(TileMap, (totalTiles) * sizeof(Tile));`

Assuming `Tile` struct is properly defined, it should work as expected : alloc enough space for  a table of `totalTiles` tiles.